# Android Asynchronous Http Client (loopj) and the Persistent Cookie Store

Tags: android, http, cookies, android-asynctask

I am new to Android Development. Had a few questions on what is the best way to make the libraries mentioned above work optimally.

Currently, I have three activities in my app. MainActivity, LoginActivity and HomeActivity. The app launches the MainActivity which is supposed to check if the person is logged in. If the person is logged in, redirect to Home, else redirect to Login.

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), I created a RestClient class. I can successfully make a request in my LoginActivity and get a response. This is my code for the login.

```
public void login() {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put(AUTH_PARAMETER_EMAIL, mEmail);
        params.put(AUTH_PARAMETER_PASSWORD, mPassword);

        RestClient.setCookieStore(new PersistentCookieStore(this));
        RestClient.post(AUTH_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                showProgress(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                String response_status = null;
                try {
                    response_status = response.getString(AUTH_RESPONSE_STATUS);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                            "ERROR: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
                if (response_status.equals(AUTH_SUCCESS_STATUS)) {
                    finish();
                } else {
                    mPasswordView
                            .setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                    mPasswordView.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e, String content) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "ERROR: " + e.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }

        });
    }
```

**Questions**

1. This is going to create a new cookie store each time a request is
   made. Where should i put it so that it is only created once? Should
   i put it in the onCreate of the MainActivity and then assign it to a
   global variable? Is that the best practice?
2. In my MainActivity, how can I check for the session cookie that was
   sent from the server? I know it is in shared preferences, but how
   can i get it? The documentation doesnt say what variable it will be
   stored under in the SharedPreferences.
3. When I need to logout someone, do I delete the shared preferences or
   erase the cookie store or both? Are they automatically kept in sync?
4. When the app restarts, how do i initialise the cookie store from the saved data in the sharedpreferences?
5. **If you know of any open-sourced code that properly implements this, Ill be happy to look at it and answer these questions myself. Just provide a link!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is what I have done until now. It works, but I am not sure if it is best practice.

1) The cookie store initialises from the sharedpreference. so just create a new one each time you need it. be sure to use the same context each time. I am using `getApplicationContext()`

2) and 4) The cookie store handels it all for you. Just create a new one with the same context as the one you created earlier. As long as you are consistent, the cookies will initialise properly.

3) the cookie store keeps the shared preferences and its local attributes in sync so just call `(new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext())).clear();`

**My Code**

RestClient.java

```
public static void setCookieStore(PersistentCookieStore cookieStore) {
    client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
RestClient.setCookieStore(new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()));
```

MainActivity.java

```
private void loginRouter() {
    PersistentCookieStore mCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(
            getApplicationContext());
    List<Cookie> cookies = mCookieStore.getCookies();
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        if (c.getName().equals("session")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    launchSplashPage();
}
```

Comment: Hey, very interesting things you mentioned here. Where do I put the `.clear` for the logout?