# Loopj Async HTTP not using cookie store to set request header

Tags: android, session, cookies, loopj

I am trying to build an Android client that can authenticate with a Pyramid server that uses redis based sessions. I am trying to use Loopj's Async HTTP library for Android to handle networking.

I am trying to implement the Persistent Cookie Storage system as described in the library's web page: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/; as well as this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661216/3438497.

The following is my implementation of the HTTP client (again, as recommended by the documentation).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;

import com.app.createalogue.clapp.R;
import com.loopj.android.http.*;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.ByteArrayEntity;

public class CtlgRestClient {

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(
            Context context,
            String url,
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler
    ) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url, context), responseHandler);
    }

    public static void get(
            Context context,
            String url,
            RequestParams params,
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler
    ) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url, context), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(
            Context context,
            String url,
            RequestParams params,
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler
    ) {
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url, context), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(
            Context context,
            String url,
            JSONObject json,
            AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler
    ) {
        ByteArrayEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity((json.toString()).getBytes());
        client.post(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url, context), entity, RequestParams.APPLICATION_JSON, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl, Context context) {
        return context.getString(R.string.server_ip).concat(":6543/") + relativeUrl;
    }

    public static void setCookieStore(PersistentCookieStore cookieStore) {
        client.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
    }

    public static void addHeader(String header, String value) {
        client.addHeader(header, value);
    }
}
```

My login activity then has the following code that is intended to set up Persistent Cookie Storage:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    CtlgRestClient.setCookieStore(new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()));
    Log.d(TAG, "Login Commences");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

My login activity is launched by the Main Activity if a logged in check with the server fails.

On debugging the app, I can see that the session token isn't being set in the header:
[image: Screenshot of client state on debug mode]

So I guess my question is what am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any clarity on how to properly configure the HTTP Client to automatically store and set session cookies. Alternate best practice suggestions to solve my current challenge would also be great!